# textarea is not filling table cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am having trouble with my controls keep causing the table cells increasing.

I have an application here:http://jsfiddle.net/XM8hG/8/embedded/result/

To see the code please access this link: http://jsfiddle.net/XM8hG/8/

Please open the app and follow the basic steps below:

1. When you open app, click on the "Add Question" button to append a table row.
2. In the row you appended click on "Open Grid" and select button "3", You will see a slight gap above and below the textarea,  open the grid again and select button "26" and you will see a bigger gap generated above and below the textarea.

I don't want any gaps above or below the textarea I want the textarea to fill the table cell. But how can I do this because I have already set the height to 100%.

Below is the css for the textarea:

```
.textAreaQuestion{
    width:auto;
    resize:none;
    height:100%;
    font-size:100%;
    display: block; 
    overflow:auto;

}
```

Below is a jquery code where I am trying to fill the table cell, at the moment it does it for when the "Add Question" button is clicked on.

```
function setWidth() {
    var questionCellWidth = $("#qandatbl_onthefly tbody .question").width();
    var questionCellHeight = $("#qandatbl_onthefly tbody .question").height();
    $(".textAreaQuestion").css({
        "width": (questionCellWidth - 6) + "px",
        "height": (questionCellHeight) + "px"
    });
}
```

​

Comment: You override the `height:100%`. Inspect the element with developer tools.

Comment: I made a suggestion some time ago about this module that you forget about all the script and get your css working with hardcoded html first. Then reverse engineer any dynamic html insertion..... Would have saved you time chasing silly bugs like this. So often the case.....seems like doing something the right way would take too long, when in reality it saves time in the long run

Comment: should probably still do it... module still looks terrible compared to most modern UI's and display is inconsistent across browsers

Comment: @charlietfl I am still trying with just the css and html but can't seem to figure it out. But I am trying your method on css and html only. Problem is that the way  Itried to tackle it was with jquery method but I am trying to do it without the jquery method above and wanting to achieve this with css only

Comment: right...you need a solid css framework first, before enhancing with script. Unfortunately development approach was backwards and now have script creating bandaids.

Comment: @charlietfl Here is a fillde with basic html with your css included but you can see that the textarea does not go all the way as the cursor starts halfway up: http://jsfiddle.net/BpWes/

Comment: OK.. html is invalid with improper TD closing tag and you have no css for TD vertical align. Personally I would never have used tables in the first place. They are not as flexible for dynamic layouts and don't animate well

Comment: also `.question{ height:100%}`  http://jsfiddle.net/BpWes/1/

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your update but problem is that the textara still doesn't fill textarea when applying this in the original jsfiddle which is updated: http://jsfiddle.net/XM8hG/19/

Comment: missing the point of throwing out most of original fiddle... to be honest would be best to start from scratch if you hope for a reasonable display. There is poorly constructed css in original

Comment: @charlietfl I know what you are saying but I don't have control over the design, I am just helping out fixing the layout, I am suppose to be doing the back end of the site but my partner is struggling with this so I posted it on SO. I doubt we will have time starting from scratch as need to finish it in couple of days, can you at least see where the problem is and then I will try an sort it out from there?

Comment: @charlietfl I will try and find a way of including a way to expand the table using a button in the basic html/css fiddle so I can expand the table and then see if I can use css to expand the textarea with the table cell

Comment: will result in more bandaids...and more time than getting css right to start. Is up to you but judging by numbers of posts regarding this module...which can easily be 100% developed from scratch in 1 to 1.5 days... I'm sure you must be getting tired of it

Comment: @charlietfl There will be a way :). I am tired of it but to be honest this is the last thing, everything in the module is actually completed. This is actually the very last thing, everything else in the module works perfectly.

Comment: edefintiely a way... already displayed in demo above I gave you with textarea filling cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set up a [new example](http://jsfiddle.net/P32hg/7/) showing how to style the `textarea` inside several `div` elements. This example includes CSS which automatically scales the width/height of the `textarea` to match the contents on the right. I tried to follow the logic and structure of your original post, but started from scratch using `div` elements. Hope this code is useful. It aims to allow for individual question and answer entry, with the possibility to add new question/answer sets.

Comment: The textarea starts in the middle, I know you make it look like textarea to fill the whole cell, so when I enter a piece of text it should be able the top of the table cell

Comment: Here is a fillde with basic html with your css included but you can see that the textarea does not go all the way as the cursor starts halfway up: http://jsfiddle.net/BpWes/

Comment: I made a comment to the original jsFiddle hopefully fixing the problem you mentioned earlier (turns out Chrome works with 100% height `textarea` elements in a table cell, but not many other browsers do). This new jsFiddle has been refactored to use `div` elements instead of a table.